# African American Walla

Tags: library, sound-libraries, crowd, walla

Does anyone know of sources for wallah\crowd librarys focused on African American \ AAVE (preferably southern) voices ?

Answer (score 1):

I found some walla/crowd sounds on soundsnap.com. They are titled Urban... You can easily tell what they are saying though so I am not sure if that is what you are looking for but those are the best I can find. -Hope this helps.